# Unordered Associative Container constraint for std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, std, unordered-map, c++-concepts

I've updated to a new version of visual studio 2019 (I think 16.6->16.9) and a piece of code that was compiling is now not.

I've put a replication of the error in godbolt below but the long and short is that I've written a function whose parameter is contrained to take in std::unordered_map's.

This once worked but now this is no longer working and all the compiler outputs is:

error C7602: 'Write': the associated constraints are not satisfied

Which is really not useful.  If anybody has tips on debugging C++ concepts that would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Latest VS2019 with command line: /std:c++latest
https://godbolt.org/z/WKadvn6sv

Latest Clang with command line: -std=c++20
https://godbolt.org/z/Mrxoxqco9

Comment: You should really post the relevant code into the question - site policy is not to trust crucial content at external sites to remain available (even answers should quote the relevant part whilst providing a link).

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was in the required sub concept 'Modifiable'.  It requires a swap function of this signature and what worked before doesn't now:

```
{ a.swap( ContainerType() ) };
```

If I swap it to this it now works:

```
{ a.swap( a ) } -> std::convertible_to<void>;
```

Perfect?  Not too sure as possibly the arg a should be arg b and another template argument introduced into my Modifiable concept.

One big question remains - why doesnt all this come as standard in C++?

Answer (score 0):

The compilers are correct in rejecting, because your

```
{ a.swap( ContainerType() ) };
```

constraint is requesting a swap function that accepts a temporary `ContainerType` variable. Clang 11 says as much, albeit at the end of an impressively verbose error report:

```cpp
<source>:104:12: note: because 'a.swap(ContainerType())' would be invalid:
non-const lvalue reference to type 'unordered_map<...>' cannot bind to a
temporary of type 'unordered_map<...>'
        { a.swap( ContainerType() ) };
                  ^
```

The readability of the messages has fortunately improved with time, but this part was already very readable and correct.

I'd express the constraint as just `{ a.swap(a) };` without the return type check. It doesn't matter that swapping something with itself would be nonsensical, all this says is "`ContainerType` has a member function `swap` that can be invoked on (and accepts) non-const lvalue references to `ContainerType`". The non-constness is implied by `requires(ContainerType a)`.